# How do you prevent throwing exceptions in functions that return promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Functions that return promises should not throw exceptions but instead reject the promise, but what's the best practice for ensuring that this will always be the case? For example, even if I have an extremely simple class method like this...

```
foo(x) {
  return this.promiseReturningApi.someMethod('bar', x);
}
```

...exceptions could be thrown if `this.promiseReturningApi` is undefined or `someMethod` is not a function (unless it's called after the first function in a promise chain).

To ensure that an exception is never thrown, is it necessary to always use a try-catch block like this:

```
foo(x) {
  try {
    return this.promiseReturningApi.someMethod('bar', x);
  } catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}
```

(Or use something like `Promise.resolve().then(() => this.promiseReturningApi.someMethod('bar', x))`)
for any function that will return a promise, or how else would one ensure that exceptions are not thrown?

Comment: `foo` is an example I'm giving of a function that returns a promise, since it simply returns the return value of a function that returns a promise. Even though it's so simple, `foo` itself could throw an exception, so would it be necessary to surround the body of foo in a try-catch block?

Comment: This is what Bluebird has [`Promise.try()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html) for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of committing the `explicit promise constructor anti-pattern, this would work:

```
foo(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(this.promiseReturningApi.someMethod('bar', x));
  });
}
```

In the absence of any error being thrown, this will return the promise yielded by `promiseReturningAPi` as is. If an uncaught error is thrown anywhere, be it in the `this.promiseReturningApi.someMethod` line for whatever reason, or possibly even further down inside the call chain (such as inside `promiseReturningApi`, depending on how it is written), then the promise returned by `foo` will be rejected for that error reason. This is due to the specification of how thrown errors inside the "executor" (the function passed to `new Promise`) are handled--namely, they result in a rejected promise.

However, you should think long and hard about whether you really want to turn what is in essence an error in program logic (for example, a missing `someMethod`) into a rejected promise. You may find it is a better structure for your program to let "real" errors be errors, and bubble up and be reported as errors are, and reserve rejected promises for failed asynchronous operations such as a network request failing.

Comment: That makes sense. I would leave `foo` as is without the try-catch or `Promise` constructor.

Comment: If you don't have Bluebird and `Promise.try()`, then personally, I like the OP's own suggestion of `Promise.resolve().then(() => this.promiseReturningApi.someMethod('bar', x))) ` better than this answer which does smell like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is the best practise

```js
/**in provider**/
foo(x) {
  return this.api.method(x); //Promise
}

/**in component**/
this.provider.foo('cat')
  .then((res) => { console.log(res) }) //resolved
  .catch((err) => { console.log(err) }) //rejected
```

Answer (score -1):

In the function that returns the promise you could use `promise.catch(...)` like mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch instead of the `try`/`catch` wrapper.  This would potentially allow you to just return `this.promiseReturningApi.someMethod('bar', x);`.

Comment: You mean within `promiseReturningApi.someMethod`, `promise.catch(...)` should be used? But for example, if `this.promiseReturningApi` is undefined, that could still cause an exception to be thrown.